# How to plot layers of tupples on same plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, tibble

I am trying to plot the time and NDVI for each region on the same plot. I think to do this I have to convert the date column from characters to time and then plot each layer. However I cannot figure out how to do this. Any thoughts?

```
list(structure(list(observation = 1L, HRpcode = NA_character_, 
    timeseries = NA_character_), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(observation = 1:6, time = c("2014-01-01", 
"2014-02-01", "2014-03-01", "2014-04-01", "2014-05-01", "2014-06-01"
), ` NDVI` = c("0.3793765496776215", "0.21686891782421552", "0.3785652933528299", 
"0.41027240624704164", "0.4035578030242673", "0.341299793064468"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), structure(list(observation = 1:6, time = c("2014-01-01", 
"2014-02-01", "2014-03-01", "2014-04-01", "2014-05-01", "2014-06-01"
), ` NDVI` = c("0.4071076986818826", "0.09090719657570319", "0.35214166081795284", 
"0.4444311032927228", "0.5220702877666005", "0.5732370503295022"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), structure(list(observation = 1:6, time = c("2014-01-01", 
"2014-02-01", "2014-03-01", "2014-04-01", "2014-05-01", "2014-06-01"
), ` NDVI` = c("0.3412131556625801", "0.18815996897460135", "0.5218904976415136", 
"0.6970128777711452", "0.7229657162729096", "0.535967435470161"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)))
111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to clean your data. The first element in this list is empty

```
df = df[-1]
```

Now we need to make a `data.frame`

```
df = do.call(rbind, df)
```

I am going to add a `region` variable, change the name of `NDVI` to remove the space,
change `ndvi` into a numeric vector, and change `time` into a `Date` object

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% 
  mutate(region = factor(rep(1:3, rep(6, 3)))) %>% 
  rename(ndvi = ' NDVI') %>% 
  mutate(ndvi = as.numeric(ndvi)) %>% 
  mutate(time = as.Date(time))
```

Now we can use `ggplot2` to plot the data by region

```
library(ggplot2)
g = df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = ndvi, col = region)) +
  geom_line()
g
```

Which gives this plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with `lubridate` to handle dates and `dplyr` to make the binding of the `data.frames` easier to understand.

Note that the group names are taken from the names of the list, and since those don't exist in the data you provided, we have to set them in advance.

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
names(data) <- 1:3
data <- bind_rows(data, .id = "group")
data$time <- ymd(data$time)
setnames(data," NDVI","NDVI")
data$NDVI <- as.numeric(data$NDVI)
ggplot(data, aes(x=time,y=NDVI,color=Group)) + geom_line()
```

[image]